# mapping custom object kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections, mapping

I have a custom object:

```
data class MoneyTransaction(
    val amount: Double,
    val category: String
)
```

I have a list of `MoneyTransaction`. I want to create a map out of that list where keys are categories, and the values are the total amount according to the category. Kotlin has functions like `groupBy`, `groupByTo`, `groupingBy`. But there is no tutorial or documentation about those, so I can't figure it out. So far I got this:

```
 val map = transactionList.groupBy({it.category},{it.amount})
```

But this doesn't give the total amount, just separate amounts on each category

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: “there is no tutorial or documentation about those” — Where did you look? The official documentation comes up as the [first](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) and [second](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-grouping.html) links when I search the web for `Kotlin groupBy`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you group your transactions by category

```kotlin
transactionList.groupBy { it.category }
```

this gives you a `Map<String, List<MoneyTransaction>>` after that you need to sum up the amounts

```kotlin
transactionList.groupBy { it.category }
  .mapValues { (_, transactionsInCategory) -> 
    transactionsInCategory.sumOf { it.amount }
  }
```

This will give you a `Map<String, Double>` with the value representing the sum of all transactions in the category.

Comment: sorry again, but how can i filter out some categories here?

Comment: you can filter them out beforehand:


`transactionList
  .filter { it.category in listOf("a", "b") }
  .groupBy { it.category }
  .mapValues { (_, transactionsInCategory) -> 
    transactionsInCategory.sumOf { it.amount }
  }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) and then [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html):

```
transactions.groupingBy(MoneyTransaction::category)
    .fold(0.0) { acc, next -> acc + next.amount }
```

`groupingBy` here would return a  `Grouping<MoneyTransaction, String>`, which is an intermediate collection of the groups. Then you `fold` each of the groups by starting from 0, and adding the next transaction's amount.

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Arrays.kt#L11321), the `groupingBy` call doesn't actually does any actual "grouping" - it just creates a lazy `Grouping` object. So effectively, you are going through the collection only once.